# get a json file in local

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, local, getjson

I am developping an app using phonegap and jquery mobile. I am new with all those technologies.
I have to get a json file to get data. I don't know how to do that in local. I tried getjson but the file is not find by my app. I have to get the json file from a local server.

Can someone help me to get data from a json file which is in local, if it's possible. 
(I am french, sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: Hi! Are you developing for Android, or iPhone, or Blackberry?

Comment: Did you add whitelist exception to your file `res/xml/cordova.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON file is situated in an external location (= not inside your folder `www`), make sure that you added the the address of your local machine as a whitelist exception.

For more information, check the online doc: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

For knowing very quickly whether the problem really comes from there, you can simply add `*` (or `.*`) to your file `res/xml/cordova.xml`:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

If the above doesn't work, you may try the following instead:

```
<access origin=".*" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your idea but nothing change. I get an error when a try to get my json file

Comment: I put my json file on my phone an dit works perfectly. I am going on with that. It is not perfect but it's work.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I had done that before. I used XMLHttpRequest and a relative path, it works. It likes this: xhr.open('GET','../json/hello.json'). I still not found a better way to get it.